# IE8 doesnt display some images

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to edit a wordpress theme and I'm getting some problems with some images that just don't want to appear on IE8. Other versions of IE render the website as it should, but IE8 gives me this headache that I don't know how to cure.

Please [take a look](http://pelerinaje.tapet-online.ro/).

I really don't have any clues why this is happening.

Help!

Comment: I can see no difference between IE9 and IE8. Caching issues? Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: That's odd, cause I'm always changing the browser&document modes in IE and the error appears only on version no. 8. I cleared the cache, but the problem persists.

Comment: Noh, someone from above provided a solution for my problem and now it's all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with your CSS on IE8. Try adding "width:30%;" on the div that holds the image something like this:

```
<div class="hentry post publish post-1 odd author-admin category-oferte-pelerinaje" id="post-32">
    <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
<A title="Pelerinaj la Schitul Sfantului Ierarh Modest – Judetul Arges" href="http://pelerinaje.tapet-online.ro/pelerinaj-la-schitul-sfantului-ierarh-modest-judetul-arges/"><IMG class="archive-thumbnail featured" alt="Pelerinaj la Schitul Sfantului Ierarh Modest – Judetul Arges" src="http://pelerinaje.tapet-online.ro/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/117491_ierah-modest-220x150.jpg" width=300 height=225></A>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the images having this CSS rule:

```
max-width: 100%;
```

To fix it, you can remove that rule altogether if you don't actually need it, remove it just for Internet Explorer 8 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660652/ie8-css-selector)), or add these two CSS rules to the parent `a` tag:

```
display: block;
width: 300px;
```