# particular css class will be executed in IE8 browser and border-radius not working

Tags: html, css

1.I have the following class in CSS file

```
.dashboard-area {
width:1200px;
}
```

I havethe above code / css class wil be included in IE8 browser instead of all browsers. I do not need to give this as separte CSS and makes the thing like. how can I give conditon in CSS code itself to execute in IE browser only.

[IE8 css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660652/ie8-css-selector)

2.border - radius not working in IE8 browser but working in all other higher version of IE.

how can I implemeent "**border-radius"** to work in all browsers of IE (7,8,9).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this but you can target IE8 with this:

```
@media all\0 { 
    .someSelector { 
        color: brown; 
    } 
}
```

Or

```
.someSelector  {
    left: -8px\0;
}
```

IE8 doesn't support border-radius http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius but you could use a polyfill like [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) to achieve it.

**Regardless I recommend you to use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)**

Comment: i dont want any custom plugin to set border raidus then how can i ?