# css: is '*html {}' equivalent to (note the space) '* html {}'?

Tags: css, netbeans

Netbeans highlights presumed errors deep down in some libraries attached.
Skimming the code, there are rules that - I think - have a simple to correct typo. For instance in

...\sites\all\modules\contrib\quicktabs\quicktabs_tabstyles\tabstyles\zen\zen.css

this rule

```css
*html ul.quicktabs-tabs.quicktabs-style-zen li{
  margin-bottom:-5px;
}
```

can be 'corrected' inserting a space after the `*`, thus becoming

```css
* html ul.quicktabs-tabs.quicktabs-style-zen li{
  margin-bottom:-5px;
}
```

and the errors have gone.

Am I breaking something doing so, specifically WRT Windows Explorer 6, that I cannot test?

Comment: the first rule is invalid and the second rule will target nothing because there is no element with `html` as child.

Comment: Since `html` is the ultimate parent the asterisk makes no sense to me.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: note these rules are located in widely used libraries, and repeated (I mean the *html) in several places, mostly commented WRT explorer6. I tend to think they know something I don't know... if you are sure about your comment, please convert it to an answer. To clarify, seems more probable to me that Netbeans rules are not enough deep to handle this case.

Comment: this is a very old hack related to the actual dead browser IE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660652/ie8-css-selector so for me it's invalid

Comment: This is the star html css hack targetting old internet explorers like your ie6 . If you really need to support that browser you can use the version with the space before the html selector. http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/filters/star-html/?path2=/css/filters/star-html/

Comment: @Joschi: I don't need to touch IE in none of its incarnations :) Indeed the only approximation I have available is Edge. The page you indicated seems to suggest that my question (Am I breaking something etc) can be answered clearly **no**, nothing is broken.

Comment: @CapelliC Yes, you can safely even remove this declaration without breaking anything

Comment: And even if removing it _did_ affect any browser, in this particular case it would be only a very very minor layout issue. No sweat.